# How to return value from form created with Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to get the return value from the form created with `Activator.CreateInstance`, but although the return value is set as public variable I only get the error in the calling form. Here is the code

```
    private void zButtonInsert1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType("MyNamespace." + this.form_name);
        using (var form = Activator.CreateInstance(type, UIB, ID) as Form)
        {
            if (form != null)
                form.ShowDialog();
                 this.ID = form._id; //Here I got the error
        }
    }
```

Here is the error message

> 'Form' does not contain a definition for '_id' and no extension method '_id' accepting a first argument of type 'Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In the called form the value (lastID) is assigned to public variable

```
  _id = (int)kon.lastID;
```

Comment: `Form` doesn't have that field or property. You'd probably need to use reflection to get that too. You seem to know an awful lot about the type of form you want at this point, so why are you not just calling the constructor?

Comment: Form does have that property and its value is populated with correct value I inspected that in the Debugger. I am comming from Visual FoxPro and I am rather new to C# so I am not sure what the question is? Do you mean why I am not just instantiating form in the usual way with `Form frm = new Form()` ?

Comment: No, `Form` doesn't - you can [check the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx). Your subclass of `Form` might, but that's not what you cast your object to. But I'll ask again, why are you not just calling e.g. `new MyForm(UIB, ID)`?

Comment: The content of forms is different and it can behave in a couple of ways depending on parameters supplied. So I just set a couple of properties (form name, Behaviour, Id, table, field etc) and I am done with any new form that I have to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to work with typed objects. But here I suppose you want to create object using type name and you don't want / can't to cast the object to desired type.

Even in this case, since you know your forms have an `_id` field, you can force them to create `Id` property and in fact force them to implement an interface and when reading value, cast it to he interface.

For example

```
public interface IFormWithId
{
    int Id {get;set;}
}
```

And implement interface for your classes:

```
public partial class SomeForm: IFormWithId
{
    public int Id {get;set;}    
    public SomeForm(int id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Then when reading value use such code:

```
var id = ((IFormWithId)form).Id;
```

If for any reason you don't want to use interfaces, you can consider these options:

**If `_id` is private or protected field**

If `_id` is private or protected field and the form doesn't have a property which exposes the field, then the only solution to find its value is using reflecten. For example:

```
var field = form.GetType().GetField("_id", /*Use GetProperty for property*/
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
var value = field.GetValue(form);
```

**If `_Id` is a public field or property**

You can use `dynamic` this way:

```
var id = ((dynamic)form)._id;
```

Comment: You're welcome :) don't neglect using interfaces in cases which you can use them. They will act as a Contact for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use get property, field .... like this

```
var value = type.GetProperty("SomeProperty").GetValue(object)...;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are typecasting your instance as `Form` and that by default doesn't have any property with name `_id` so you are getting error.

You can use reflection to get the property.

```
private object GetProperty(Form obj, string propName)
{
   var p = ob.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
   if(p != null)
   {
       return p.GetValue(ob);
   }
   return null;
}
```

and then you can call in your code like below -

```
if (form != null)
{
   form.ShowDialog();
   object val = GetProperty(form, "_id");
   this.ID = TypeCastValHere(val);
}
```

don't forget to type cast the return value from object to `this.ID' type